# Find a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ such that the eigenvector associated with $\lambda = 1$ equals...

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find a $2\times 2$ matrix $A$ such that the eigenvector associated
>   with $\lambda = 1$ equals $\operatorname{span}\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
>  2\\1 \end{array} \right)$ is the **only** eigenspace.

I believe $A =SBS^{-1}$. So can we use $S$ with first column equal to $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
2\\1 \end{array} \right)$ and second column equal to anything that makes it invertible, and $B = I_2$, then just compute $SBS^{-1}$ to find $A$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your answer cannot be right, for if $B=I$ then $A=SS^{-1}=I$ and the eigenspace will be all of $\Bbb R^2$.

---

The simplest way to get what you want is to realise that as $A$ has only one independent eigenvector, it will not be diagonalisable and will have a Jordan form instead.  The matrix
$$A=\pmatrix{2&1\cr1&0\cr}\pmatrix{1&1\cr0&1\cr}\pmatrix{2&1\cr1&0\cr}^{-1}
  =\pmatrix{3&-4\cr1&-1\cr}$$
will do what you want.

---

If you have not yet studied Jordan forms, you can use a bit of trial and error.  The easiest way to make sure that $A$ has $1$ as an eigenvalue, with eigenvector $(2,1)$, is to specify
$$A-I=\pmatrix{1&-2\cr k&-2k\cr}\ ,\tag{$*$}$$
which gives
$$A=\pmatrix{2&-2\cr k&1-2k\cr}\ .$$
Now to make sure that $1$ is the **only** eigenvalue, we want the trace to be $2$, so $3-2k=2$, so $k=\frac12$ and
$$A=\pmatrix{2&-2\cr {\textstyle\frac12}&0\cr}\ .$$

Comment: Can you choose $S$ to be whatever you like (under the assumption it's invertible)?

Comment: To get the eigenvalues you want, $S$ can be any invertible matrix.  To also get the eigenvector you want, this eigenvector must be the first column of $S$.  See also updated answer for an alternative method.

Comment: Why does the trace being equal to $2$ imply that $1$ is the only eigenvalue?

Comment: The trace is the sum of the eigenvalues (funfact).  So if the trace is $2$ and one eigenvalue is $1$, then the other eigenvalue is also $1$.

Comment: Can it also happen that one eigenvalue is $2$ and the other $0$, or $50$ and $-48$, etc.?

Comment: Yes but not in this case because we made sure at the beginning that one of the eigenvalues was $1$.

Comment: Can you please explain that part a little more? Sorry, I understand everything else.

Comment: If you row-reduce the RHS of $(*)$ you will see that you have eigenvalue $1$ with eigenvectors span$\{(2,1)\}$.

Comment: How did you know that form would have $1$ as an eigenvalue so naturally?

Comment: Because I made the left hand side $A-I$.  If you wanted eigenvalue $\lambda$ then I would have made it $A-\lambda I$.  Hope you don't mind if I say, but you seem a bit shaky on the basic definitions of eigenvalues and eigenvectors - you need to make sure you are absolutely on top of what these words mean.

Comment: No, I appreciate your honesty, and I agree that my understanding is not as deep as I would like. I can find eigenvalues and eigenvectors relatively easily, but it seems like basic manipulations of the concepts is what I find tricky. Can you recommend any sources that will help me with these?

Comment: Not sure about sources - if you have a decent textbook or lecture notes, they should have everything you need.  It's more a case of being sufficiently familiar with the area that you can immediately see that, for example, row-reducing $A-\lambda I$ is the same as solving $(A-\lambda I){\bf v}={\bf0}$, which is the same as $A{\bf v}=\lambda{\bf v}$, which means ${\bf v}$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.  Also things like seeing without calculation that row-reducing the RHS of $(*)$ will give a zero row.

Comment: @Carley, nice discussion.

Answer (score 0):

i wonder if it is easier to construct the matrix $A - I$ first. we can use the property that $A$ has eigenvalue $1$ and an associated eigenvector $(2,1)^T,$ then $A-I$ will have eigenvalue $0$ and an associated eigenvector $(2,1)^T.$

$(A-I)(2,1)^T = 0$ tells us that the second column of $A-I$ is $-2$ times the first column of $A-I.$ to avoid any further relations between the columns, we can require the first column be not the zero column. i believe any matrix of the form $\pmatrix{a & -2a\cr b & -2b}$ with the constraint $a^2 + b^2 \neq 0$ should do for the matrix $A-I.$

now add $1$ to the diagonals to get the matrix $A.$